# ReactJs: How to use condition in arrow function

Tags: reactjs, rendering, arrow-functions

How can I correct use `if else` condition in `arrow function`.

//code

```
renderHeadline = label => (
 <Headline layout= {.... }>
  .......
 </Headline>
);
```

I want to check if `label != null` before this rendering.

Any suggestion

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ternary operator`

```
renderHeadline = label => label ? (
    <Headline layout= {.... }>/*...*/</Headline>
) : null
```

Comment: Dupocas is this going to be inside renderHeadline = label => ( ...//here ternary or conditional rendering  );   ?

Comment: I've update the answer to reflect your use case. `conditional rendering` can only be used inside `jsx` block otherwise the `function` will just return a boolean

Comment: Dupocas if i don't render `null` in `else` . So `renderHeadline = label => label && ( ........ );`

Comment: You can render whatever you want in `else` (`:`) block. `condition ? <CompA />  : <CompB />`

Answer (score 1):

@Dupocas' answer is an alternative to what you are asking here. Still, if you want to use an `if` condition in the function you should use an [explicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) for this arrow function.

Arrow functions have two body type. Implicit and explicit ones. If you don't need any other logic before returning something you can use an implicit return as you do in your example. But, if you need to do something before the return, you can use explicit return and hence should use curly braces there.

```
renderHeadline = label => {
  if (label) {
    return <Headline layout={....}>.......</Headline>;
  }
};
```

Otherwise, if your true intent is not using an if condition but return the `Header` if `label` is not null, then here is a one liner.

```
const renderHeadline = label => label && <Headline layout={...}>.......</Headline>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what bothers you here are the parentheses. For one instruction, you don't have to put curly brackets, for several instructions however, you have to put them.

```
const myFunction = label => return //the arrow points to what should be returned, we don't need the "return"
```

```
const myFunction = label => {
 instruction
 return //here, however, we will add an explicit return instruction
}
```

So once you have your curly brackets, there is nothing disturbing anymore and you can use `if else` like you always have.

```
renderHeadline = label => {

 if (condition) {
   return <Element1 />
 }
 else () {
   return <Element2 />
 }

};
```

Now as to why we're using parentheses!

```
(
 <Headline layout= {.... }>
  .......
 </Headline>
)
```

is like

```
return (
 <Headline layout= {.... }>
  .......
 </Headline>
)
```

As you know, in Javascript, it's not necessary to add a semicolon. However when compiling, it will look for the first opportunity to put it for you. Say you wrote this:

```
return <Headline layout= {.... }>//; <- it will put a semicolon here and it won't compile
  .......
 </Headline>
```

However, with an opening bracket on the same line as `return` will work and it will tell Javascript not to add a semicolon until there is a closing parenthesis.

**edit**: In fact, this seems to work too

```
return <div>
  <MyComponent />
</div>
```

but this won't

```
return//; <- a semi-colon is added here 

//valid but unreachable
<div>
  <MyComponent />
</div>
```

We have to add parentheses

```
return (
<div>
  <MyComponent />
</div>
)//; <- the semi-colon will be added here, all good
```